# WinRT and persisting struct to and from an array of bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Using .NET 4.0 I can quickly convert a struct to and from an array of bytes by making use of the Marshal class. For example, the following simple example will run at around 1 million times per second on my machine which is fast enough for my purposes...

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ExampleStruct
    {
        int i1;
        int i2;
    }

    public byte[] StructToBytes()
    {
        ExampleStruct inst = new ExampleStruct();

        int len = Marshal.SizeOf(inst);
        byte[] arr = new byte[len];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(inst, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return arr;
    }
```

But the Marshal class is not available under WinRT, which is reasonable enough for security reasons, but it means I need another way to achieve my struct to/from byte array.

I am looking for an approach that works for any fixed size struct. I could solve the problem by writing custom code for each struct that knows how to convert that particular struct to and form a byte array but that is rather tedious and I cannot help but feel there is some generic solution.

Comment: Is binary serialization out of the picture? Another question is if performance is important it seems odd to involve `AllocHGlobal`.

Comment: Good point about using AllocHGlobal for each call. My actual implementation is little more complicated to be more efficient. It caches the len, arr and ptr so that each actual call to convert to bytes only involves the Marshal.StructureToPtr and Marshal.Copy. The posted code was just a simplified example.

Comment: The problem I had with binary serialization is the overhead. A struct with a single int32 field would be serialized to something like 140 bytes. If your structures are fairly large then this overhead is no big deal but in my scenario I have alot of objects that are relatively small. So converting the struct to just the actual 4 bytes it contains is a big saving in my case.

Comment: Fair enough, MSDN isn't being friendly in helping determine what of Expressions can be used. I'm sure a Reflection/Expressions combo could build you a converter in the full .Net, but not so sure in Metro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be a combination of Expressions and Reflection (I'll leave caching as an implementation detail):

```
// Action for a given struct that writes each field to a BinaryWriter
static Action<BinaryWriter, T> CreateWriter<T>()
{
    // TODO: cache/validate T is a "simple" struct

    var bw = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BinaryWriter), "bw");
    var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "value");

    // I could not determine if .Net for Metro had BlockExpression or not
    // and if it does not you'll need a shim that returns a dummy value
    // to compose with addition or boolean operations
    var body = Expression.Block(
       from f in typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredFields
       select Expression.Call(
           bw,
           "Write",
           Type.EmptyTypes, // Not a generic method
           new[] { Expression.Field(obj, f.Name) }));

    var action = Expression.Lambda<Action<BinaryWriter, T>>(
        body,
        new[] { bw, obj });

    return action.Compile();
}
```

Used like so:

```
public static byte[] GetBytes<T>(T value)
{
    // TODO: validation and caching as necessary
    var writer = CreateWriter(value);
    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    writer(new BinaryWriter(memory), value);
    return memory.ToArray();
}
```

To read this back, it is a bit more involved:

```
static MethodInfo[] readers = typeof(BinaryReader).GetTypeInfo()
    .DeclaredMethods
    .Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("Read") && !m.GetParameters().Any())
    .ToArray();

// Action for a given struct that reads each field from a BinaryReader
static Func<BinaryReader, T> CreateReader<T>()
{
    // TODO: cache/validate T is a "simple" struct

    var br = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BinaryReader), "br");

    var info = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo();

    var body = Expression.MemberInit(
       Expression.New(typeof(T)),
       from f in info.DeclaredFields
       select Expression.Bind(
           f,
           Expression.Call(
               br,
               readers.Single(m => m.ReturnType == f.FieldType),
               Type.EmptyTypes, // Not a generic method
               new Expression[0]));

    var function = Expression.Lambda<Func<BinaryReader, T>>(
        body,
        new[] { br });

    return function.Compile();
}
```

Comment: I like the approach of building an expression and compiling it to give best performance.

Comment: I don't suppose this will be allowed in a Windows Store app since it's dynamically generating code to be executed, correct?